# Read in Lat/Long Data, and then print out points on a Geospatial Map in Python

Tags: python, google-maps

I have a CSV file that contains 911 calling information (location, time, reason)

I want to strip the Latitude and Longitude variables from the CSV file and map them out on a 'geospatial' map.

I'm envisioning the map like a sample google Maps page, with the multiple pins at each location being linked to the reason of the 911 call.

Is there any way I can get this done using Python, or I do have to install an external library? Is there a Google application I have to work with?

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to look at the following modules:

- For reading data from a text file (CSV file is a
  Comma-Separated-Values text file): Look at the following functions of
  `numpy`: `numpy.genfromtxt` or `numpy.loadtxt`
- For plotting onto maps, you're best off installing and using the
  module `basemap`. It's technically part of `matplotlib` but you have
  to install it separately. It is pretty simple and works incredibly
  well, producing professional style maps and has a lot of geodata for
  topographies etc already included.

Have a look at some examples from those modules I mentioned above and I doubt you'll have a problem doing what you want.

The `basemap` module won't include streets or stuff down to a city scale though. For this you probably want to find a module that can read openstreetmap info, maybe a module like [`osmapi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osmapi) although I haven't tried it myself

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help mjp. I'll take a look at what you posted and will hopefully be done with my project by the end of the weekend.

Comment: If this answers the question, remember to mark the answer as so (tick icon on the left under the voting up/down arrows). Glad I could help.